# How do I prove that $-\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x} \to 0$ as $x\to +\infty $?

Tags: limits

I thought that I might simply show that:
$-\sqrt{x-1} \approx  -\sqrt{x}$ when x $\rightarrow +\infty$ ,
so we have $ -\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} = 0 $.

I want to ask, is my approach rigorous enough? Is there a better way to show this?

Comment: Simplify the equivalent expression $(-\sqrt{x - 1} + \sqrt{x})\Big(\frac{\sqrt{x - 1} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x - 1} + \sqrt{x}}\Big)$.

Comment: You could try [using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits to prove this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preciselimdirectory/PreciseLimit.html), but you have the right idea here. Since you have $x \to \infty$, you need to prove that for all $\epsilon$, there exists an $M$ such that $x > M \implies \lvert -\sqrt{x-a}+\sqrt{x}-0 \rvert < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**: You really want to consider the limiting behavior of

$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1}=\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}}\cdot(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Viewed this way (and with a basic calculus theorem) it suffices to show that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.  This would give a rigorous proof of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not rigourous at all. In the sense you use it, $\approx$ is not really mathematically defined.

*A counter-example:*

You might say $\sqrt{x^2-x}\approx \sqrt{x^2}$ when $x\to +\infty$, and likewise conclude that $\;\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{x^2-x}\to 0$.

However, supposing $x>0$
$$\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{x^2-x}=\frac{x^2-(x^2-x)}{\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{x^2-x}}=\frac x{x\biggl(1+\sqrt{1-\dfrac 1x}\biggr)}\to \frac12.$$